# Are global variables in Pascal Script zero-initialized?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When I declare a global variable in `[Code]` section (Pascal Script) of Inno Setup script, is it automatically initialized to zero/empty value? Or do I have to explicitly initialize it (e.g. in [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup))?

```pascal
var
  GlobalNumber: Integer;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  // Is this necessary?
  GlobalNumber := 0;

  Result := True;
end;
```

From my experience, the variables are zero-initialized. Though, I'm not sure if I just have not been lucky.

I've done 10.000 iterations of a test code. The global variables (or various types, integer, string, pointer) were always zero-initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables are automatically initialized in *Pascal Script* afaik.

I thought that I also read this in earlier times somewhere in the docs, but I could not find a clear statement in documentation again. However, if you look at the examples from Pascal Script's official manual, variables are also not always initialized there. In the first code on [this page](https://github.com/remobjects/pascalscript/wiki/Using-RemObjects-Pascal-Script) for example, strings are added to `Messages` without having it initialized before.

Comment: Thanks. I hope for a more authoritative source. But official examples are not bad.

Comment: Here is an example from the InnoSetup docs where they use a global variable of type `Boolean`, without initializing it, assuming that is has a default value of `False`: https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm

Answer (score -2):

global variables are always zero initialized, but for local variables this is not true.

it is all explained in the docs:
https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse24.html

Comment: Pascal Script is not Pascal.