# Getting compile error "Semicolon (;) expected" when initializing variable in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am writing Inno Setup script code for user input of `Username` and `Password`. I want to skip this page for user and take constant value for `Username` and `Password`.

For example username is 12345 want to make it constant initialization.

Here is my code.

```pascal
var
  Username, Password: String;
```

When I modify this code like:

```pascal
  Username : String = '12345';
  Password : String = 'MyPassword';
```

I'm getting compile error:

> Semicolon (;) expected.

Could anyone please help me to fix it. I am newbie in Pascal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inno Setup Pascal Script does not support initializing variables at a point of their declaration.

Initialize them in the [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) instead.

```pascal
var
  Username, Password: string;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Username := '12345';
  Password := 'MyPassword';

  Result := True;
end;
```

A related question: [Are global variables in Pascal Script zero-initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34015970/850848)

---

Note that your code would be correct in Pascal/Delphi. But this is Pascal Script, not Pascal.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin. Your answered help me to fix my issue.