# How do you determine if an object has be constructed in Inno Setup Pascal Script?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How do I check that my checkbox has been created / constructed and can be used to check if checked?

```pascal
[Code]

var
  MyCheckBoxThatMayExistOrNot: TNewCheckBox;

procedure Whatever();
begin
  { Check if MyCheckBoxThatMayExistOrNot exists and checked }
  if ????? and MyCheckBoxThatMayExistOrNot.Checked then
  begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the variable value against [`nil`](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Nil):

```pascal
if (MyCheckBoxThatMayExistOrNot <> nil) and
   MyCheckBoxThatMayExistOrNot.Checked then
```

An equivalent is use of [`Assigned` function](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Assigned):

```pascal
if Assigned(MyCheckBoxThatMayExistOrNot) and
   MyCheckBoxThatMayExistOrNot.Checked then
```

---

You might want to explicitly initialize the variable to `nil` in [`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) or [`InitializeWizard`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard), but it should not be necessary:  [Are global variables in Pascal Script zero-initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34015970/850848)